# How do I convert this nested foreach to linq C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda

When I tried to convert this nested foreach to LINQ, I'm unable to do it. I have tried of several ways but nothing. I didn't get the result as these foreach

```
foreach (string field in extractorResults.Keys) {
    if (fileResults.ContainsKey(field)) {
        foreach (ExtractionResult exResult in extractorResults[field]) {
            fileResults[field].Add(exResult);
        }
    } else
        fileResults.Add(field, extractorResults[field]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try, and in what way(s), specifically, was it not working?

Comment: Can you put the actual types of extractorResults, fileResults. Otherwise this is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to 'merge' two dictionaries:

```
fileResults = fileResults.Concat(extractorResults)
                 .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList());
```

Explanation:

1. Get all KeyValuePairs from both dictionaries
2. Group all KeyValuePairs by keys
3. Create new dictionary which will contain entry for each group - same key and list of all values selected from grouped KeyValuePairs. You can add `Distinct()` call after selecting values if you don't want duplications in result. Though your original foreach-based logic produces duplicates.

---

Step by step (I'll use JSON format to show data flow):

Assume you have two dictionaries with following data (actual data types do not matter here):

```
  fileResults = [
     { key:"a", value: [1,2] },
     { key: "b", value: [5] }
  ];

  extractorResults = [
     { key:"c", value: [7] },  
     { key: "b", value: [3,4] }
  ];
```

After concatenating these dictionaries you will get single sequence of key value pairs

```
 [
    { key:"a", value: [1,2] }, 
    { key: "b", value: [5] },
    { key:"c", value: [7] },  
    { key: "b", value: [3,4] }
 ]
```

Next goes grouping:

```
 [
    { key: "a", items: [ { key:"a", value: [1,2] } ] },
    { key: "b", items: [ { key: "b", value: [5] }, { key: "b", value: [3,4] },
    { key: "c", items: [ { key:"c", value: [7] } ]
 ]
```

And finally we create new dictionary with entries for each group above:

```
 [
    { key: "a", value: [1, 2] },
    { key: "b", value: [5, 3, 4] },
    { key: "c", value: [7] }
 ]
```

Comment: Worked :), but I still having troubles when I'm doing cast from List to IList.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, at the end since I was unable to cast from a Dictionary to IDictionary this worked for me:

```
var mergeResults = fileResults.Concat(extractorResults)
                    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList())
                    .Where(kvp => !fileResults.ContainsKey(kvp.Key));

                var kvpMergeResults = mergeResults as IList<KeyValuePair<string, List<Result>>> ?? mergeResults.ToList();
                fileResults.Add(kvpMergeResults.First().Key, kvpMergeResults.First().Value);
```